# Linux tar: only --transform certain files

Tags: linux, bash, tar, working-directory, transform

I'm writing a bash script that packages my application into a TAR file. The files aren't arranged on disk how they need to be arranged in the TAR file, so I decided to use the --transform option.

However, it seems that the --transform command is applied globally instead of being applied to the files that are included after.

Example:

```
tar \
--exclude='webmanager/bin/dev' \
--exclude='webmanager/.config.ini' \
--show-transformed-names \
--create --gzip --verbose \
--file 'output.tgz' \
-C '../../../' \
'include' \
'resources' \
'webmanager' \
'rootconfig.php' \
-C 'webmanager/bin/dev' \
'index.php' \
'README.md' \
--transform='s|^|webmanager/|r' \
'.config.ini'
```

Basically, this code takes a file from `webmanager/bin/dev/.config.ini` and places it at `webmanager/.config.ini` in the TAR file. But I only want the .config.ini file to be transformed. Currently all the contents are being transformed and prefixed with `webmanager/`. I was hoping this command behaved like `-C` (change current directory) - where it only affects the inputs after it.

I have looked over the TAR man pages and I can't figure out how to do this properly. Please help!

Comment: Feel free to write a patch.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `--transform` option works on all the files indeed. By the way, I've found this [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20190607074040/https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_52.html) about `tar` (section 6.8 of the man page: operating only on new files) that might help you somehow.

If I may, I would suggest you a different approach: lay out the files as you need in a temporary directory (`cp` command will do), modify your .config.in with `sed` and than use `tar` to pack everything. You can create a script of even a Makefile, if you are familiar with `make`.

Comment: I recommend making hardlinks (`cp -l`) instead of copying to save time and disk space.

Comment: Yes, that's better. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AlessandroDottiContra your `page` link is dead - is this the right page/section?  https://web.archive.org/web/20190607074040/https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_52.html  if so can you have the link text state the section/option name and maybe even quote relevant info for a future-safe answer

Comment: @nhed: amended my answer by fixing the link and adding the information about the section of the man page referred as per your suggetion. Thank you!